# Varias clases de Bootstrap no "existen"

Tags: java, html, css, bootstrap

Me pasa algo muy extraño, recién comencé a utilizar bootstrap, estoy aprendiendo con tutoriales de Youtube, por lo que descargué los archivos css correspondientes de la página web oficial (bootstrap.min.css y bootstrap.css). Varias de las clases no existen en los archivos .css lo cuál me parece raro, ya que son archivos oficiales. Por ejemplo:

```
<form class="form-inline">
     <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control" type="search" placeholder="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

No me reconoce la clase .form-inline, la busqué en los .css con el bloc de notas pero no las encuentra.
Disculpen si hay algo que esté mal en el código, no llevo mucho usando ni bootstrap ni HTML. Muchísimas gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Si estás añadiendo la ruta del archivo css a tu HTML verdad?

Comment: Sí, lo que mostré fue la parte del formulario para no hacer tanto código jaja

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más probable es que estás utilizando Bootstrap 5. Si te fijas en la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/migration/#forms), verás que, por ejemplo, `form-inline` fue removido, para que en su lugar se utilice el [sistema grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/) y las [utilidades](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/utilities/).

Comment: Efectivamente era eso, descargué la versión 4.6 y ya sirve perfectamente, muchísimas gracias!